# swiftUI multiple line text not handiling as expected in the Vstack aligment

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, line

I'm facing an alignment issue when text input is multiple lines. In this example, the first section shows the left and right side text properly shown in the image. the second section, it shows text in 3 to 4 lines which disturb the alignment right side

I want to make the left make independently size during multiple lines. The right side remains as it is(no gap between 2nd title and 2nd Value ).

Code :-

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {

            Section {
                Text("single line")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            Section {
                Text("mutiple lines")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "This is long. This is long value. This is long value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct TwoLineView: View{
    var firstTitle: String
    var fistValue: String
    var secondTitle: String
    var secondValue: String
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(firstTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(fistValue)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(secondTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(secondValue).lineLimit(1)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 45)
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: Single or multiple line values. I don't want to display a gap between the title and value. (2nd section in the image has a gap between 2nd title and 2nd Value which is a bad UX experience)

Comment: So, the 2nd column looks like expected, right? It had an extra Spacer in the bottom. Adding a Spacer to the bottom of the 1st column will make it behave exactly as the 2nd one. Or is it the 1st column that looks correct? Then remove the Spacer from the 2nd one.

Comment: Remove `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` and add `Spacer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, remove  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)  and add spacer():

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {

            Section {
                Text("single line")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "Value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            Section {
                Text("mutiple lines")
            }
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "This is long. This is long value. This is long value",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
            
            TwoLineView(firstTitle: "1st Title", fistValue: "test",
                           secondTitle: "2nd Title", secondValue: "2nd Value")
        }
        
    }
    

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct TwoLineView: View{
    var firstTitle: String
    var fistValue: String
    var secondTitle: String
    var secondValue: String
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(firstTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(fistValue) //<------here
                   Spacer()     //<-------here
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(secondTitle).lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                
                Text(secondValue).lineLimit(1)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 45)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you have made to the code. Just looking at a block of code like this it is hard to see what you have done.

Comment: removed  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) and added spacer()

Comment: Add it to your answer. Code only answers are really bad.